# How to get the last folder's name where the file is stored (without using macro)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, path

I need to extract - in a cell - the last folder name where the active excel file is stored.

E.g. C:/Documents/Users/Accounting/May 2019/Expenses.xls

I want to extract/output the text "May 2019" in a specific cell by using a formula (not a macro).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this : TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"/",REPT(" ",999)),4*999-998,999))

Comment: @RonRosenfeld not sure this is actually a duplicate, but I applied the CELL() function to get the full path of the workbook...

Comment: @SolarMike I thought he already had the folder path.  Perhaps I misread.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I might have misread also, but it is a different take in terms of answer so hope it helps the OP... Cheers.

Comment: @SolarMike You have well interpreted my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went with using the CELL() function to get the full path and then cut out the last folder name.

See:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"/",REPT(" ",999)),4*999-998,999))
```

[image]

Edit, As Ron pointed out that was fixed for the number of folders... This works around that:

See:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"/",REPT(" ",999)),SUM(IF(CELL("filename",A1)<>"",LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"/","")),0))*999-998,999))
```

[image]

Note:

Localization can mean ";" instead of "," and "\" instead of "/", so take care...

Comment: Your formula depends on there being a known number of subfolders in the path string, rather than picking the next-to-last.

Comment: @SolarMike Having said that I have a localized version of Microsoft Excel 2013 (Italian version), I have "translated" your formula by using this very useful online  tool (https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/). I have outputted the file path in A1, as you did, then I used the other formula (the TRIM one). But I get the #VALUE error in the cell where I use the TRIM one.

Comment: the trim() function translates as ANNULLA.SPAZI, see a list here`: http://easy-excel.com/excel-in-other-languages/excel-functions-in-italian/

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I have translated it (and verified its accuracy through reverse translation). But I get the "#VALUE!" error. How come in your opinion? Translated formula here just for your information: {=ANNULLA.SPAZI(STRINGA.ESTRAI(SOSTITUISCI(CELLA("filename";A1);"/";RIPETI(" ";999));SOMMA(SE(CELLA("filename";A1)<>"";LUNGHEZZA(CELLA("filename";A1))-LUNGHEZZA(SOSTITUISCI(CELLA("filename";A1);"/";""));0))*999-998;999))}. If  I use your first formula, in translated version, {=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"/",REPT(" ",999)),4*999-998,999))}, instead I get a blank cell.

Comment: Why are you entering it as an array formula? I don't on my example. So all the functions exist in excel 2013? I can't check...

Comment: @SolarMike Yep they exist (I checked the arguments suggestions for each single function). I am using your last formula (Please take into account that localized versions of Excel may use different separators, such as semicolons instead of commas, this is the case for Italian version)

Comment: @ValerioS I know about the use of the different separators - have answered questions about that. But why enter it as an array formula? You have not answered that. And why are you not using the updated version I gave?

Comment: @SolarMike If you are referring to my use of curly brackets, I'm using them just here to "isolate" the code from normal speaking. I'm using this formula `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"/",REPT(" ",999)),SUM(IF(CELL("filename",A1)<>"",LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"/","")),0))*999-998,999))` thats should be your last version, if I did not miss something else

Comment: I have just tested that latest version on 4 different paths on my machine and it works fine.

Comment: @SolarMike I got the error! In your environment the symbol "/" (forward slash) is the separator between the folders. In mine it is the "\" (backslash). Thank you for your patience! :)))

Comment: Magic, glad it works. So, don't forget to accept the answer with the tick or check mark. Do note that you showed "/" in your question...

Comment: @SolarMike I wrote down the path sample without using the real output. Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=ANNULLA.SPAZI(STRINGA.ESTRAI(SOSTITUISCI(CELLA("filename";A1);"\";RIPETI(" ";999));SOMMA(SE(CELLA("filename";A1)<>"";LUNGHEZZA(CELLA("filename";A1))-LUNGHEZZA(SOSTITUISCI(CELLA("filename";A1);"\";""));0))*999-998;999))
```

Localized Italian version of @SolarMike code's.